# can't reverse django.contrib.admin.sites.index

Tags: django

I try to do the following

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, resolve
a = resolve('/admin/')
b = reverse(a[0], args=a[1], kwargs=a[2])
```

And get the following error

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'django.contrib.admin.sites.index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

How this is possible?

Answer (score 5):

Only you can reverse a urls defined on urlpatterns the admin is `reverse("admin:index")`